# The Unity Editor dosent displays the correct value

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I made a script where you can click 1 time to get 1 Coin you can see that in the `click()` Function. My problem is when I have 100 Coins the Unity Editor doesn't shows that I have 100 Coins, it just shows 10 but the coin value is still 100.

`click()` is connected through a trigger in Unity that activates every time I click a Button and then it adds 1 Coin to the Coin value which is connected to a text so I can display it in the Editor.

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Press : MonoBehaviour
{
    public Text TextScore;
    public long coins;

    public void Start()
    {
        coins = 0;
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        TextScore.text = "Coins" + coins;
    }

    public void click()
    {
        coins = coins+= 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: Reduce the font size of the TextScore in the inspector. And why
coins = coins+= 1;
? Just use
coins += 1;
. I hope this will help you.

Comment: How many objects have ```Press``` on them?

Comment: Is your text width just too small to show the full text?

Answer (score 0):

It seems the width of the UI Text is the problem.
So the text of the UI Text is still "Coins100", but the width of it is not enough to display all the text.

[Your problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LgVWl.png)

[My solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rOpZ5.png)

Please try to resize the **UI Text** in the Inspector
[Rect Transform Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I70XL.png)

Or please check the **Best Fit** option of the Text Component in Inspector
[UI Text Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NHHP2.png)

And why not use **coins++**?